# How can I make GDB stop at SIGTRAP only at breakpoints?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to debug a program that often causes GDB to stop and display SIGTRAP when it is not at a breakpoint. It happens when loading dynamic libraries and other ordinary stuff. There are like 1,000 of these occurring before my breakpoint is finally hit, so it's non-feasible for me to manually "continue" all these irrelevant SIGTRAPs. But if I use the command `handle SIGTRAP nostop noprint`, then GDB will not stop at my breakpoint.

It seems like there must be a way to educate GDB so that it understands which SIGTRAP is good for stopping, and which is no good for stopping. Clearly GDB knows whether it is at a breakpoint, because the output is very reliably different: at a breakpoint, it mentions "breakpoint" and shows the breakpoint number--but at any other SIGTRAP, it just says "SIGTRAP". So instead of printing the message about a SIGTRAP, I'd really like GDB to just say to itself, "wow, this is a SIGTRAP and there is no breakpoint here--look at me, I'm about to stop and print a useless SIGTRAP message that completely ruins the debug session! How about I just continue quietly?" Please let me know if someone has a way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You can set [catchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html#Set-Catchpoints) to catch the SIGTRAP signal and add commands to decide whether to continue or to stop. In this handler, you can inspect [convenience variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html) such as [`$_siginfo`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html#extra-signal-information) for the reason for the signal.

Of particular interest is `$_siginfo.si_code`, its value depends on the signal that is delivered. The [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) Linux manual page describes the exact relations. You can find the numeric values for those `SI_USER`, `SI_KERNEL`, etc. codes by compiling a program or looking in headers (on my system it uses the header `/usr/include/bits/siginfo.h`). Some values I have encountered are:

- 0x00 (0): `SI_USER`
- 0x80 (128): `SI_KERNEL`
- 0x02 (2): `TRAP_TRACE`

With this information in hand, here is an example that catches SIGTRAP and prints the reason, then continues:

```
catch signal SIGTRAP
commands
 p $_siginfo.si_code
 c
end
# Set another breakpoint for testing
break sleep
```

Now consider this test program that sleeps 5 seconds, then triggers a debug trap on x86(-64):

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    for (;;) {
        sleep(5);
        asm("int3");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program keeps stopping `gdb` at the `int3` line because the signal is caught (`si_code` happens to be 0x80, `SI_KERNEL`), but then the instruction is repeated again. So to skip this instruction, the program counter (`$pc`) must be incremented. After doing so, I learned this information about `SIGTRAP` and `si_code`:

- Breakpoints trigger SIGTRAP with code 128 (`SI_KERNEL`).
- After continuing the breakpoing, a SIGTRAP with code 2 (`TRAP_TRACE`) is received (because of the catchpoint for `SIGTRAP`).
- The `int3` instruction triggers SIGTRAP with code 128. Thus you needs something to differentiate the instructions.

Here are the final GDB commands that skip the `int3` traps and still keep the breakpoints functional:

```
catch signal SIGTRAP
commands
 silent # do not print catchpoint hits
 # ignore the int3 instruction (this address was looked up at
 # the tracepoint using print $pc)
 if $pc == 0x400568
  set $pc++ # skip int3
  c
 end
 # Ignore TRAP_TRACE that is used for breakpoints
 if $_siginfo.si_code == 2
  c
 end
end
```

A final note: SIGTRAP is used internally by the debugger, it is possible that the above catches too much. This was tested with GDB 7.10 on Arch Linux.

Comment: By the way, this is architecture-dependent, but the idea is generally applicable. Maybe you have to `set $pc += ...` instead, or change the `si_code` numbers.

Comment: `silent` doesn't work in my gdb.  What can I use instead?

Comment: @Alex Define "does not work", it prevents a message from being printed, but it does not automatically continue after the catchpoint is hit.

Comment: @Alex What have you tried? The `silent` command should be the first one after `commands`, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Oh, OK,  that was the issue.  I was typing it as the second command-- never thought it could make a difference.