# How to conditionally ignore SIGTRAP in GDB?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to debug a program which triggers an unwanted SIGTRAP in a specific routine. This signal is triggered in a library, but the same caller always shows up in the backtrace. How can I tell GDB to ignore this signal if the caller is [some function], instead of breaking on it?

I've tried to use `skip function [some function]` and even `skip file [file that triggers SIGTRAP]` (from [5.3 Skipping Over Functions and Files](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files)), but GDB still broke at that line. And `continue` doesn't seem to support conditionals either. I'd take any solution that doesn't require a modification of the debugged program, including Python scripts for GDB. If relevant, you may also assume that an error is written to `stderr` before SIGTRAP is triggered.

<sub>Two years ago, someone asked [How can I make GDB stop at SIGTRAP only at breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667795/how-can-i-make-gdb-stop-at-sigtrap-only-at-breakpoints). This hasn't received any answers, so I hope that the weaker version of the question (ignoring some specific SIGTRAPs) is answerable.</sub>

Comment: I would try `catch signal all`, then use `commands` on that to change the `handle pass` setting for `SIGTRAP` depending on whether this one should be ignored.  I don't actually know if this will work.  Another try would be to have a Python `stop` event handler that posts a `continue` to the command loop if the stop is not one that is desired.

Comment: @TomTromey Thanks for your comment! I tried to avoid `catch signal SIGTRAP` (let alone `all`) because it captures too much. Lekensteyn's solution below does exactly what I want. A slightly more involved version of your suggestion has been described in [his other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667795/how-can-i-make-gdb-stop-at-sigtrap-only-at-breakpoints/33498809#33498809). Take a look if you're interested!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the problem at the source (the trigger of the `SIGTRAP` signal) or after the fact has happened (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33498809/427545) on ignoring certain SIGTRAPs). Below I'll explain how to handle the first case (avoiding the trigger).

If you have code like:

```
void debug_break() {
    asm("int3");
}
```

then you can set a breakpoint with commands to return immediately:

```
break debug_break
commands
 return
 continue
end
```

If you cannot return because the code is mixed:

```
/* some code here */
asm("int3");
print_error();
```

then you can skip a *line* with the `jump` command. Assuming that the `int3` line is 1337, use:

```
break file.c:1337
commands
 j +1
 c
end
```

If the stuff is on a single line (`asm("int3"); print_error();`, then change the line jump to incrementing the program counter (`set $pc++`). This assumes that the instruction is one byte.